# Is encoding needed in this decryption?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, character-encoding

I have a Encryption – Decryption scenario as shown below.

> //[Clear text ID string as input]  -- [(ASCII GetByte) + Encoding] -- [Encrption as byte array]  -- [Database column is in VarBinary] -- [Pass byte[] as VarBinary parameter to SP for comparison]
>
> //[ID stored as VarBinary in Database] -- [Read as byte array] -- [(Decrypt as byte array) + Encoding + (ASCII Get String)] -- Show as string in the UI

My question is in the decryption scenario.  After decryption I get a byte array.  I am doing an encoding (IBM037) after that. Is it correct?
Is there something wrong in the flow shown above?

```
private static byte[] GetEncryptedID(string id)
{
    Interface_Request input = new Interface_Request();
    input.RequestText = Encodeto64(id);
    input.RequestType = Encryption;

    ProgramInterface inputRequest = new ProgramInterface();
    inputRequest.Test_Trial_Request = input;

    using (KTestService operation = new KTestService())
    {
        return ((operation.KTrialOperation(inputRequest)).Test_Trial_Response.ResponseText);
    }
}


private static string GetDecryptedID(byte[] id)
{
    Interface_Request input = new Interface_Request();
    input.RequestText = id;
    input.RequestType = Decryption;

    ProgramInterface request = new ProgramInterface();
    request.Test_Trial_Request = input;

    using (KTestService operationD = new KTestService())
    {
            ProgramInterface1 response = operationD.KI014Operation(request);
            byte[] decryptedValue = response.ICSF_AES_Response.ResponseText;
            Encoding sourceByteFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM037");
            Encoding destinationByteFormat = Encoding.ASCII;

            //Convert from one byte format to other (IBM to ASCII)
            byte[] ibmEncodedBytes = Encoding.Convert(sourceByteFormat, destinationByteFormat,decryptedValue);
            return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(ibmEncodedBytes);

        }
    }

    private static byte[] EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
    {
        byte[] dataInBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
        Encoding destinationByteFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM037");
        Encoding sourceByteFormat = Encoding.ASCII;

        //Convert from one byte format to other (ASCII to IBM)
        byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(sourceByteFormat, destinationByteFormat, dataInBytes);
        return asciiBytes;
    }
```

Comment: The flow appears to be correct. What is the problem here? Are you getting errors? Is the ciphertext garbled? Is it working or are you wondering how to improve it?

Comment: @akton No errors. I am encrypting after making IBM037 encoding. While decryption why I again do a IBM037 encoding. It should be something like "decoding", isn't it?

Comment: You are using an encoding mechanism to convert bytes to and from a C# string and byte array. I suppose you could call it decoding.

Comment: I found the answer -while decryption process, after decrypting I am converting IBM037 byte to ASCII byte. Thats why there is encoding coming in.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question also (with more explanatory variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer -while decryption process, after decrypting I am converting IBM037 byte to ASCII byte. Thats why there is encoding coming in. I have updated the code in the question also (with more explanatory variables)